# How to create and use async command abstract class?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, command

I am developing something using wpf mvvm.

Currently, my implementation style is a bit unusual.

This is to prevent the sauce from gathering in one place.

Async void should be avoided, but I don't know how to avoid it.

Any solution?

Below is the source I used. (RelayCommand is generic and I need to create a new async command.)

<View.xaml>, <View.xaml.cs>

```
<BusyIndicator IsBusy="{IsBusy, mode=TwoWay}">
    <Listbox ItemsSource="{Binding Models}"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding OnClickButtonCommand}"
            CommandParameter="whether the value(string) exists or not"/>
</BusyIndicator>

this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
```

<ViewModel.cs>

```
public ViewModel() { }

private isBusy;
public isBusy
{
    get => isBusy;
    set => SetField(ref isBusy, value);
}

public ObservableCollection<Model> Models { get; set; }

public ICommand OnClickButtonCommand { get => new ButtonCommand(this); }
```

<ButtonCommand.cs>

```
public ButtonCommand : RelayCommand
{
    private ViewModel viewModel;
    public ViewModel(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    public override async void Execute(object obj)
    {
        viewModel.IsBusy = true;
        await Task.Delay(1500);

        viewModel.Models = new ObservableCollection<Model>(await Data());
        viewModel.IsBusy = false;
    }

    private async Task<List<Model>> Data()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        var data = new List<Model>();
              ...
        return data;
    }
}
```

*Inserting await delay is to prevent debugging warning.

<CommandBase.cs>

```
public interface IRelayCommand : ICommand
{
    new void Execute(object obj);
}

public abstract class RelayCommand : IRelayCommand
{
    public RelayCommand() { }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add    => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object obj)
    {
        if (obj?.ToString().Length == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
        //return canExecute == null || this.canExecute.Invoke(parameter);
    }
    public abstract void Execute(object obj);
}
```

And if my code is weird or there is better code, please let me know!

Thanks. :)

- https://johnthiriet.com/mvvm-going-async-with-async-command/

I've seen a lot of this site and other samples, but it's an example using a typical fuction,

so I can't apply it...

Comment: to avoid async void you shoud return Task or Task<T> in your Execute method

Comment: @TheOverrider It is not necessary for me.
I just want to avoid async void and implement using abstract class.

Comment: At https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/april/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-commands you find a wrapper for ICommand. But ICommand defines `void Execute (object? parameter);` so you have to implement an async void method if you implement this interface. I agree that async voud has to be minimized, but Event handlers are an exception (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)

Comment: @Michael  Thanks for the documentation reference.

So, is it irrelevant if I continue to use this RelayCommand and not create an AsyncCommand?

The implementation is very different, but I think the behavior is the same.

Comment: The main reasons for implementing asynchronous commands are (from documentation reference):
*This practice makes the code more testable.* and *It awaits the result to ensure that any exceptions in the asynchronous command logic will be properly raised to the UI thread’s main loop.*

If you want to test your command method with an unit test, and this method is async void, you cannot await the result. If this problems doesn't affect you, you can use the normal ICommand interface.

Comment: In this implementation, this is complete nonsense.
The point of using commands is an abstraction from the type where they will use and from the methods they use.
Controlling the state of the ViewModel in which they are set from commands is completely absurd.
In fact, you are not creating a team, but an add-on over your ViewModel (Parent or Main ViewModel?) And creating confusing links between them.

Comment: @EldHasp The reason I implement this is because if all methods exist in the ViewModel, it is difficult to find and complicated later. (ex. 50,000 lines)

I think my structure is similar to this link.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7hRmbdE9eY

Comment: And now, instead of a method, you will have a separate implementation of the command for each?
I don't see that this can simplify the code in any way.
It is possible in a command to encapsulate some functions common to all instances (asynchronous execution, busyness, "catching" exceptions, validation interface, etc.).
But the specific method that it will execute must be passed when creating an instance.

Comment: The state of a command is precisely its state, not the state of the ViewModel.
One command may be busy (= true) and another may be ready to run (IsBusy = false).
And how are you going to transfer the states of different commands with one ViewModel property?

Comment: If you make the implementation of the command, then you need to make it much more developed with much more functionality.
Then there really may be at least some benefit to you.
At least elementary: asynchronous commands imply that there will be many threads in the application.
And as a minimum, you need to provide for the marshaling of CanExecuteChanged to the UI thread.

Comment: @EldHasp TThe implementation I'm talking about doesn't deviate from the above code structure.

Except for IsBusy, everything else has different functions.
When IsBusy = true, all functions are not used and wait for loading and completion. I use asnyc to keep the loading bar running.

In the case of CanExecuteChanged I am aware too. Currently, it is an imitation and will continue to evolve.
I'm a beginner developer, so I don't understand exactly, but I think this will be of great help for large-scale projects.

Comment: In the case of a general ICommnad Function, I think it will be difficult to find as I said before. Of course, there are many things I don't know because I lack technical skills.
In the project I am working on, a lot of UserControls are attached to one window as navigation. This UserControl is managed as one in the Window ViewModel.
(This is because A-UserControl and C-UserControl share data with each other.)
Therefore, without defining functions, we try to classify them as Commands Class as in the above post. My English is not that good. If you understand and can give me any advice, please.

Comment: English is also difficult for me.
I'm from Russia.
For more specific advice, you need to provide more details on the terms of your task.
If you compose some general static class of commands for navigation, then in some form it is possible to apply a variant close to your implementation.
In this case, the command will be a View component.
And in the hierarchy, such a command is located ABOVE the ViewModel.
But you need to somehow correctly build abstractions in order to get rid of circular references: the command refers to the ViewModel, and the ViewModel back to it.

Comment: @EldHasp Currently my way is that the command configuration is wrong which makes the viewmodel refer to the viewmodel again? Are you saying that if you configure this as a static class or interface, it will be better than the current one?

Comment: My system looks like this. However, the Action of RelayCommand is not used and the logic goes directly into the Execute of PlusCommand.cs. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1052346/ICommand-Interface-in-WPF

Comment: A command is a universal interface and can be used in any layer of the application.
Just like the default .Net types: int, string, Point, etc.
My pretense does not apply to the team, in general, but specifically to your implementation.
Creating a circular reference is almost always a bad thing.

Comment: From your explanations, I ponchl that you need this for some other level. Therefore, I assumed that in this case it should be removed from the ViewModel into some separate type (maybe a static Helper), which would allow breaking the circular reference.
But this is not some kind of strict recommendation, but a vague (and possibly incorrect) guess.

Comment: Your basic implementation looks very dubious too.
Why, in general, check a parameter for casting to an empty string?
Casting to a string itself can be a lengthy operation.
At the same time, it is absolutely not clear why an empty string is considered not correct, and null -correct?
If your task specifically requires it, and the implementation is made under its specific conditions, then the general, abstract name of the "RelayCommand" class is misleading.
A class with this name should be abstract from the methods it uses.
And inside such a class, no parameter processing should take place.

Comment: @EldHasp Circular references are not recommended. understand.
So, in my case, if I break the circular reference, how to chain the function?

Should I use the viewModel, view object as a static or interface implementation?

For the basic implementation, I do not know the exact logic because I implemented it by referring to the Internet.

That's why I've written about this and even more about Async.

Comment: I am busy right now.
I will try to throw off an example of the implementation of commands and their use for your code later.
As a last resort, I will do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the `AsyncCommand` implementation from James Montemagno's MVVM-Helpers library (currently also implemented in the Xamarin Community Toolkit), you can take a look at the implementation here: [AsyncCommand implementation](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers/blob/master/MvvmHelpers/Commands/AsyncCommand.cs)

You can use it like this:

Install the [Refactored.MvvmHelpers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Refractored.MvvmHelpers/) nuget package.

MyViewModel.cs

```cs
public class MyViewModel {

    //other code goes here (Models collection, IsBusy, etc)

    public ICommand DoWorkCommand => new AsyncCommand(DoWorkAsync);

    public ICommand DoWorkWithParameterCommand => new AsyncCommand<bool>(DoWorkWithParameterAsync);

    private async Task DoWorkAsync(){
        //simulate work
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    private async Task DoWorkWithParameterAsync(bool itemExists){
        //simulate work
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

MyView.cs

```xml
<BusyIndicator IsBusy="{IsBusy, mode=TwoWay}">
    <Listbox ItemsSource="{Binding Models}"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding DoWorkCommand}" />
    <Button Command="{Binding DoWorkWithParameterCommand}" CommandParameter="False"/>
</BusyIndicator>
```

Comment: This implementation is a bit far from me.
Create a method in the ViewModel.

In this case, my solution is different.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### **An example of my implementation of base classes:
BaseInpc,
RelayCommand, RelayCommandAsync,
RelayCommand<T>, RelayCommandAsync<T>.**

There are a lot of verbose documentation tags in the code.

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Simplified
{
    /// <summary>Base class with implementation of the <see cref="INotifyPropertyChanged"/> interface.</summary>
    public abstract class BaseInpc : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <inheritdoc cref="INotifyPropertyChanged"/>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>The protected method for raising the event <see cref = "PropertyChanged"/>.</summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the changed property.
        /// If the value is not specified, the name of the method in which the call was made is used.</param>
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        /// <summary> Protected method for assigning a value to a field and raising 
        /// an event <see cref = "PropertyChanged" />. </summary>
        /// <typeparam name = "T"> The type of the field and assigned value. </typeparam>
        /// <param name = "propertyFiled"> Field reference. </param>
        /// <param name = "newValue"> The value to assign. </param>
        /// <param name = "propertyName"> The name of the changed property.
        /// If no value is specified, then the name of the method 
        /// in which the call was made is used. </param>
        /// <remarks> The method is intended for use in the property setter. <br/>
        /// To check for changes,
        /// used the <see cref = "object.Equals (object, object)" /> method.
        /// If the assigned value is not equivalent to the field value,
        /// then it is assigned to the field. <br/>
        /// After the assignment, an event is created <see cref = "PropertyChanged" />
        /// by calling the method <see cref = "RaisePropertyChanged (string)" />
        /// passing the parameter <paramref name = "propertyName" />. <br/>
        /// After the event is created,
        /// the <see cref = "OnPropertyChanged (string, object, object)" />
        /// method is called. </remarks>
        protected void Set<T>(ref T propertyFiled, in T newValue, [CallerMemberName] in string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (!Equals(propertyFiled, newValue))
            {
                T oldValue = propertyFiled;
                propertyFiled = newValue;
                RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);

                OnPropertyChanged(propertyName, oldValue, newValue);
            }
        }

        /// <summary> The protected virtual method is called after the property has been assigned a value and after the event is raised <see cref = "PropertyChanged" />. </summary>
        /// <param name = "propertyName"> The name of the changed property. </param>
        /// <param name = "oldValue"> The old value of the property. </param>
        /// <param name = "newValue"> The new value of the property. </param>
        /// <remarks> Can be overridden in derived classes to respond to property value changes. <br/>
        /// It is recommended to call the base method as the first operator in the overridden method. <br/>
        /// If the overridden method does not call the base class, then an unwanted change in the base class logic is possible. </remarks>
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(in string propertyName, in object oldValue, in object newValue) { }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Simplified
{
    /// <summary> A class that implements <see cref = "ICommand" />. <br/>
    /// Implementation taken from <see href="https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread2390714-page4.html#post13535649"/>
    /// and added a constructor for methods without a parameter.</summary>
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        protected readonly CanExecuteHandler<object> canExecute;
        protected readonly ExecuteHandler<object> execute;
        private readonly EventHandler requerySuggested;

        /// <inheritdoc cref="ICommand.CanExecuteChanged"/>
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        /// <summary> Command constructor. </summary>
        /// <param name = "execute"> Command method to execute. </param>
        /// <param name = "canExecute"> Method that returns the state of the command. </param>
        public RelayCommand(ExecuteHandler<object> execute, CanExecuteHandler<object> canExecute = null)
           : this()
        {
            this.execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc cref="RelayCommand(ExecuteHandler{object}, CanExecuteHandler{object})"/>
        public RelayCommand(ExecuteHandler execute, CanExecuteHandler canExecute = null)
                : this
                (
                      p => execute(),
                      p => canExecute?.Invoke() ?? true
                )
        { }

        private readonly Dispatcher dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;

        /// <summary> The method that raises the event <see cref="CanExecuteChanged"/>.</summary>
        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            if (dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                invalidate();
            }
            else
            {
                _ = dispatcher.BeginInvoke(invalidate);
            }
        }
        private readonly Action invalidate;
        private RelayCommand()
        {
            invalidate = () => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            requerySuggested = (o, e) => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += requerySuggested;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc cref="ICommand.CanExecute(object)"/>
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return canExecute?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc cref="ICommand.Execute(object)"/>
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            execute?.Invoke(parameter);
        }

    }


}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Simplified
{
    /// <summary>A class that implements asynchronous commands with the execution
    /// of the <see cref="RelayCommand.Execute(object)"/>  method in Task. </summary>
    /// <remarks>Only one call to the <see cref="RelayCommand.Execute(object)"/>
    /// method is allowed at a time.
    /// During the execution of the method, the <see cref="IsBusy"/> flag is set and
    /// the <see cref="RelayCommand.CanExecute(object)"/> method of the command will return false.
    /// The <see cref="INotifyDataErrorInfo"/> interface is implemented to notify about
    /// an erroneous call to the <see cref="RelayCommand.Execute(object)"/> method before
    /// the previous execution completes and about exceptions during the
    /// execution of <see cref="RelayCommand.Execute(object)"/>.
    /// To notify about changes in property values, the <see cref="INotifyPropertyChanged"/>
    /// interface is implemented.</remarks>
    public class RelayCommandAsync : RelayCommand, ICommand, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
    {
        /// <inheritdoc cref="INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged"/>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        /// <inheritdoc cref="INotifyDataErrorInfo.ErrorsChanged"/>
        public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

        /// <summary>The command is in the execution state of the <see cref="RelayCommand.Execute(object)"/> method.</summary>
        public bool IsBusy { get; private set; }

        /// <inheritdoc cref="INotifyDataErrorInfo.HasErrors"/>
        public bool HasErrors { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>Exception from the last execution of the <see cref="RelayCommand.Execute(object)"/> method.</summary>
        public Exception ExecuteException { get; private set; }

        // A flag indicating a "call to execute busy a command" error.
        private bool isBusyExecuteError;

        /// <summary>Sets a value to the <see cref="IsBisy"/> property and notifies of its change.</summary>
        /// <param name="isBusy">The value for the property.</param>
        protected void SetIsBusy(bool isBusy)
        {
            if (IsBusy != isBusy)
            {
                IsBusy = isBusy;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, Args.IsBusyPropertyEventArgs);
                RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Sets the HasErrors property and reports an entity-level error.</summary>
        /// <param name="hasErrors">The value for the property.</param>
        protected void SetEntityHasErrors(bool hasErrors)
              => SetHasErrors(hasErrors, Args.EntityLevelErrorsEventArgs);

        /// <summary>Sets the HasErrors property and reports an entity or property level error.</summary>
        /// <param name="hasErrors">The value for the property.</param>
        /// <param name="args">Argument with data about the error level.</param>
        protected void SetHasErrors(bool hasErrors, DataErrorsChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (HasErrors != hasErrors)
            {
                HasErrors = hasErrors;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, Args.HasErrorsPropertyEventArgs);
            }
            ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
        }


        /// <summary>Sets a value to the <see cref="ExecuteException"/> property and notifies of its change.</summary>
        /// <param name="exception">The value for the property.</param>
        protected void SetExecuteException(Exception exception)
        {
            if (ExecuteException != exception)
            {
                ExecuteException = exception;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, Args.ExecuteExceptionPropertyEventArgs);
            }
        }

        /// <inheritdoc cref="RelayCommand(ExecuteHandler{object}, CanExecuteHandler{object})"/>
        public RelayCommandAsync(ExecuteHandler<object> execute, CanExecuteHandler<object> canExecute = null)
            : this(new AsyncData(execute, canExecute))
        { }

        /// <inheritdoc cref="RelayCommand(ExecuteHandler, CanExecuteHandler)"/>
        public RelayCommandAsync(ExecuteHandler execute, CanExecuteHandler canExecute = null)
            : this(new AsyncData(execute, canExecute))
        { }

        // The field for storing additional, auxiliary data generated
        // during the generation of the asynchronous method, wrapping
        // the one obtained in the constructor.
        private readonly AsyncData data;

        /// <inheritdoc cref="RelayCommand(ExecuteHandler{object}, CanExecuteHandler{object})"/>
        protected RelayCommandAsync(AsyncData data)
            : base(data.ExecuteAsync, data.CanExecuteAsync)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.data.commandAsync = this;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc cref="INotifyDataErrorInfo.GetErrors(string)"/>
        public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            {
                if (isBusyExecuteError)
                {
                    yield return Args.BusyExecuteErrorMessage;
                }

                if (ExecuteException != null)
                {
                    yield return ExecuteException;
                }
            }
            IEnumerable errors = GetErrorsOverride(propertyName);
            if (errors != null)
            {
                foreach (var error in errors)
                {
                    yield return error;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Method overridden in derived classes to add error information</summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property to retrieve validation
        /// errors for; or null or Empty, to retrieve entity-level errors.</param>
        /// <returns>The validation errors for the property or entity.</returns>
        protected virtual IEnumerable GetErrorsOverride(string propertyName)
            => null;

        /// <summary>A class with persistent elements to avoid re-creating them frequently.</summary>
        public static class Args
        {
            public const string BusyExecuteErrorMessage = "Called the execution of a command when it is busy.";

            public static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs IsBusyPropertyEventArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsBusy));
            public static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs HasErrorsPropertyEventArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(HasErrors));
            public static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs ExecuteExceptionPropertyEventArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ExecuteException));

            public static readonly DataErrorsChangedEventArgs EntityLevelErrorsEventArgs = new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(string.Empty);
        }

        /// <summary>A class for storing additional, auxiliary data and methods that are generated
        /// when generating asynchronous methods that wrap the synchronous methods received
        /// in the constructor.</summary>
        protected class AsyncData
        {
            public RelayCommandAsync commandAsync;
            public async void ExecuteAsync(object parameter)
            {
                if (commandAsync.IsBusy)
                {
                    commandAsync.isBusyExecuteError = true;
                    commandAsync.SetEntityHasErrors(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    commandAsync.SetIsBusy(true);

                    try
                    {
                        await Task.Run(() => execute(parameter));

                        commandAsync.isBusyExecuteError = false;
                        commandAsync.SetExecuteException(null);
                        commandAsync.SetEntityHasErrors(false);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        commandAsync.SetExecuteException(ex);
                        commandAsync.SetEntityHasErrors(true);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        commandAsync.SetIsBusy(false);
                    }
                }
            }

            public CanExecuteHandler<object> CanExecuteAsync { get; }
            private bool canExecuteNullAsync(object parameter) => !commandAsync.IsBusy;
            private bool canExecuteAsync(object parameter) => !commandAsync.IsBusy && canExecute(parameter);

            private readonly ExecuteHandler<object> execute;
            private readonly CanExecuteHandler<object> canExecute;

            /// <inheritdoc cref="AsyncData(ExecuteHandler, CanExecuteHandler)"/>
            public AsyncData(ExecuteHandler<object> execute, CanExecuteHandler<object> canExecute)
            {
                this.execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));


                if (canExecute == null)
                {
                    CanExecuteAsync = canExecuteNullAsync;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.canExecute = canExecute;
                    CanExecuteAsync = canExecuteAsync;
                }
            }

            /// <summary>Creates an instance.</summary>
            /// <param name="execute">Synchronous Execute method.</param>
            /// <param name="canExecute">Synchronous CanExecute method.</param>
            public AsyncData(ExecuteHandler execute, CanExecuteHandler canExecute)
            {
                if (execute == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
                }

                this.execute = p => execute();


                if (canExecute == null)
                {
                    CanExecuteAsync = canExecuteNullAsync;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.canExecute = p => canExecute();
                    CanExecuteAsync = canExecuteAsync;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Some of the classes did not fit into the answer.
Take them [from here](https://github.com/EldHasp/CyberForumMyCycleRepos/tree/master/BindingToNumber/Simplified(engl)).

### An example of using RelayCommand for your code.

```cs
    public class ViewModel : BaseInpc
    {

        private bool _isBusy;
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get => _isBusy;
            set => Set(ref _isBusy, value);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Model> Models { get; set; }

        // Under no circumstances should you get an instance of a command in this way.
        // As such, each time the property is accessed, a NEW instance of the command is created.
        // As a result, in each element of the Window, in the ViewMode, etc. there are different instances everywhere.
        // This is a very common cause of various bugs.
        //
        //public ICommand OnClickButtonCommand { get => new ButtonCommand(this); }

        // One of the options for the correct team creation.
        private RelayCommand _onClickButtonCommand;
        public RelayCommand OnClickButtonCommand => _onClickButtonCommand
            ?? (_onClickButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteOnClick));

        // Executing command method
        private async void ExecuteOnClick(object parameter)
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            await Task.Delay(1500);

            Models = new ObservableCollection<Model>(await Data());
            IsBusy = false;
        }
        private async Task<List<Model>> Data()
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            var data = new List<Model>();

            // Some code

            return data;
        }

    }
```

In such an implementation, you can create a method for each command, its own IsBusy property and other members of which it needs.

But to a large extent, all this (except for the synchronous executing method) can be encapsulated in the command itself.
Encapsulating the execution method does not make sense, since it is because of it that the command instances differ from each other.

### My example using asynchronous commands

In the example, a blinking background, in order to understand at what moment the GUI lags occur - blinking during lags stops.
There are also several buttons to demonstrate the difference between synchronous and asynchronous method execution, and how errors and exceptions in them affect applications.
Click them in various combinations.

When errors and exceptions appear, they are displayed under the buttons at the bottom of the window.

If you have any questions during testing - ask.

```cs
using Simplified;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace RelayCommandAsyncTest
{
    public class TestViewModel : BaseInpc
    {
        private int _count;
        // Command execution counter (common for all commands)
        public int Count { get => _count; set => Set(ref _count, value); }

        // Аsynchronous command
        public RelayCommandAsync TestCommandAsync { get; }
        // Synchronous command
        public RelayCommand TestCommand { get; }
        // Synchronous command with Lags
        public RelayCommand TestLagsCommand { get; }
        // Synchronous command executing asynchronous command
        // without checking it IsBusy.
        public RelayCommand TestExecuteCommandAsync { get; }

        // Long running execution method for validating
        // an asynchronous command 
        private void ExecuteForAsync(object obj)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Count++;
            // If the command parameter is not passed,
            // then there will be an exception
            Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(obj));
        }

        // Long running execution method for creating
        // lags in a synchronous command
        private void ExecuteLags(object obj)
        {
            isExecuteLagsCommand = true;
            TestLagsCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Count++;
            // If the command parameter is not passed,
            // then there will be an exception
            Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(obj));

            isExecuteLagsCommand = false;
            TestLagsCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
        bool isExecuteLagsCommand;

        // Fast executing method for checking lags with
        // a synchronous command
        private void Execute(object obj)
        {
            Count++;

            // If the command parameter is not passed,
            // then there will be an exception
            Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(obj));
        }

        // A command that executes an asynchronous command without checking if it is busy.
        // If the asynchronous command is busy, it will generate a validation error.
        private void ExecuteCommandAsync(object obj)
        {
            Count++;
            TestCommandAsync.Execute(obj);
        }
        public TestViewModel()
        {
            TestCommandAsync = new RelayCommandAsync(ExecuteForAsync);
            TestCommand = new RelayCommand(Execute);
            TestLagsCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteLags, p => !isExecuteLagsCommand);
            TestExecuteCommandAsync = new RelayCommand(ExecuteCommandAsync);


            timer = new Timer
            (
                _ => TestCommandAsync.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(),
                null,
                0,
                5000
            );
        }

        // Timer to check for raising CanExecuteChanged from any thread.
        private readonly Timer timer;
    }

}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="RelayCommandAsyncTest.CommandTestWindow"
        x:Name="main"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RelayCommandAsyncTest" xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Common;assembly=Common"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="CommandTestWindow" Height="1000" Width="800"
        FontSize="30">
    <FrameworkElement.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded" SourceName="main">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FlashingBrush"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                    To="LightYellow"
                                    AutoReverse="True"
                                    RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </FrameworkElement.Triggers>
    <FrameworkElement.DataContext>
        <local:TestViewModel/>
    </FrameworkElement.DataContext>
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
            <Border BorderThickness="5"
                    BorderBrush="Red">
                <Grid IsHitTestVisible="False">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="80"
                                   Text="! ! !"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource validationTemplate}"/>
        </Style>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="FlashingBrush" Color="LightGreen"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <UniformGrid Columns="2">
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="Async throw Exception"
                    Command="{Binding TestCommandAsync}"
                    CommandParameter="qwerty" Margin="15"/>
            <Button Content="Async Normal"
                    Command="{Binding TestCommandAsync}"
                    CommandParameter="2000" Margin="15"/>
            <Button Content="Sync Lags"
                    Command="{Binding TestLagsCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="2000" Margin="15"/>
            <Button Content="IsBusy is not checked"
                    Command="{Binding TestExecuteCommandAsync}" Margin="15"
                    CommandParameter="0">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TestCommandAsync.HasErrors}"
                                         Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="Sync throw Exception"
                    Command="{Binding TestCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="qwerty" Margin="15"/>
            <Button Content="Sync Normal"
                    Command="{Binding TestCommand}" Margin="15"
                    CommandParameter="2000"/>
        </UniformGrid>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"  Margin="5">
            <Run Text="IsBusy:"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding TestCommandAsync.IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Run Text="&#9;"/>
                <Run Text="HasErrors:"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding TestCommandAsync.HasErrors, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Run Text="&#9;"/>
            <Run Text="Count:"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding Count}"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=button, Path=(Validation.Errors)}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="ErrorContent"
                      FontSize="15"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me a sample.

I have seen this, but it is difficult to analyze in a short period of time with my current skills. I will continue to check this and develop it.

Comment: My method of implementation was encapsulation. I can ignore concealment and access among its properties.


Please check ViewModel.cs.
If I separate ExecuteOnClick as a class, it will be a circular reference like the first time, and it doesn't matter if I inherit this?

The reason for wanting encapsulation is that it is okay if the source of the ViewModel Class is short, but if there are more than 100 functions, it is better to manage it as a class.

If not, do you manage it with '#region' ?

Comment: Any "manipulation" of ViewModel members is part of the ViewModel. BUT the command is an abstract instance that doesn't need to know anything about the ViewModel.
It just gets a method and calls it.
If you want to "unload" or split the ViewModel code because there is too much of it, then for this you need to use the methods of the ViewModel level, and not pass functionality that is not inherent in it to the command.
It is possible to split the ViewModel code into multiple files using the partial class.

Comment: Another way is to create a nested Helper class in the ViewModel, which will contain methods for working with the ViewModel.
In the ViwModel constructor, create an instance of this class linked to the current ViewModel instance.
When creating commands, pass them the methods delegates of this Helper instance.