# WPF - TextBox validation error displayed twice and not removed

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-style

### Issue description

I'm developing an application in which I have a `ListBox` where, when an element is selected, it's details are shown in an editing control.

I'm binding the `SelectedItem` to the control and, as I want to apply different `DataTemplates`, I'm trying to use VM first approach and bind directly to the control contents.

My custom `TextBox` style displays validation errors with a blue border (for the sake of the example). However, when using this approach, a red validation border is also shown and it's not being removed once the data is correct. **This is not the expected behavior**, the red border should not show at all.

I don't know if the error is in the **style** or in the **binding**.

### Example and testing

I've tried different things to try to debug the error. This is not happening with the standard style nor with a `DataContext` approach. However, I cannot use the `DataContext` approach as I will need to apply different templates to different types of elements in the list.

See the pictures below.

When the data is invalid (empty) the *"VM First + Custom style"* option shows both the blue and the red borders:

[image: Data with error border]

When I write some text, the red border is not removed:

[image: Valid data where error border should be gone]

#### ViewModels

There are two ViewModels, one for the main window and another for each element in the list:

```
public class ChildViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => SetProperty(ref _name, value);
    }
    public override string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (propertyName == nameof(Name))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
                {
                    return "The name is mandatory.";
                }
            }
            return base[propertyName];
        }
    }

}

public class ParentViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ChildViewModel _selectedItem;
    public ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> Collection { get; private set; }
    public ChildViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
    }
    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        Collection = new ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel>();
        Collection.Add(new ChildViewModel());
        Collection.Add(new ChildViewModel());
    }
}

public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public string Error => this[null];
    public virtual string this[string propertyName] => string.Empty;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Views

The `MainWindow` is just as follows, with no code behind apart from the standard.

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="400">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ParentViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Style.xaml" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
        <UserControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Content="DataContext + No style" />
                <TextBox Margin="6" Text="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <Label Content="DataContext + Custom style" />
                <TextBox Margin="6" Text="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </UserControl>
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ChildViewModel}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Content="VM First + No style" />
                        <TextBox Margin="6" Text="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <Label Content="VM First + Custom style" />
                        <TextBox Margin="6" Text="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

#### Style

This is located in a `ResourceDictionary` named "Style.xaml". The `Border` and the `ValidationErrorElement` are separated elements in order to apply different visual states for mouse over, focused...

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Opacity="1">
                            <Grid>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not displaying the error condition correctly.
WPF uses a ControlTemplate with an AdornedElementPlaceholder for this, which is set in the attached Validation.ErrorTemplate property.

A big example with implementation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68748914/13349759

Here is a small snippet of XAML from another small example:

```xml
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationFailed">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border BorderBrush="Violet" BorderThickness="2">
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                </Border>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="26" FontWeight="Bold">!</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
         
        <TextBox Margin="10"
            Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationFailed}" >
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Age">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <DataErrorValidationRule />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that. My actual style is a bit more complex with a tooltip that is displayed through an animation when an error is detected. Also I want the validation border to replace the button border instead of adding a second border around it. Thus, I've "solved" it (or worked it around) by adding `<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />` to the style.

Comment: Yes.
This "disables" the default validation error display template.
But my advice: better learn how to create and use it correctly.
This is much more useful and convenient than changing the element template every time.
You can apply one error template to several elements at once: TextBox, Label, Button, etc.

Comment: Thanks. That's true, I've noticed it, reusability is nice. I already have custom styles for all controls though. 