# Using ComboBox to set value of field from a source List<T> with two values - WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox

I need a combobox to list the items from a List with two fields :

`AcctTypeID` - This is an int (0 - 20).

`AcctTypeName` - This is a string -- ex. "Accounts Payable" (the cooresponding AcctTypeID is say 10 for Accounts Payable).

I need the `ComboBox` to show the AcctTypeName but send the AcctTypeID to the underlying field.

I promise I have spent hours seraching for this and trying every idea I can think of or find.

Answer (score 0):

Use this XAML and set or bind the `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox` to an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is your class with the `AcctTypeName` and `AcctTypeID` properties:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb" DisplayMemberPath="AcctTypeName" SelectedValuePath="AcctTypeID" />
```

You get the selected value using the `SelectedValue` property:

```
int acctTypeID = (int)cmb.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to give an exact answer to your question without some additional explanations.

For example, if you are using MVVM, then your code should be implemented like this:

```cs
    public class AcctTypeDto
    {
        public int AcctTypeId { get; set; }
        public string AcctTypeName { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
    public class AcctTypesViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<AcctTypeDto> AcctTypes { get; }
            = new ObservableCollection<AcctTypeDto>()
            {
                new AcctTypeDto(){AcctTypeId=123, AcctTypeName="Teen"},
                new AcctTypeDto(){AcctTypeId=456, AcctTypeName="Five"},
                new AcctTypeDto(){AcctTypeId=789, AcctTypeName="Seven"}
            };

        private RelayCommand _sendIdCommand;
        public RelayCommand SendIdCommand => _sendIdCommand
            ?? (_sendIdCommand = new RelayCommand<int>(SendIdExecute));

        private static void SendIdExecute(int parameter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Id={parameter}");
        }

        private RelayCommand _sendAccCommand;
        public RelayCommand SendAccCommand => _sendAccCommand
            ?? (_sendAccCommand = new RelayCommand<AcctTypeDto>(SendAccExecute));

        private static void SendAccExecute(AcctTypeDto parameter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Id={parameter.AcctTypeId}; Name={parameter.AcctTypeName}");
        }
    }
```

```xml
    <FrameworkElement.DataContext>
        <local:AcctTypesViewModel/>
    </FrameworkElement.DataContext>
    <UniformGrid Columns="1">
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding AcctTypes}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="AcctTypeName"
                  SelectedValuePath="AcctTypeId"/>
        <Button Content="Send Id" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Command="{Binding SendIdCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=comboBox}"/>
        <Button Content="Send AcctType" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Command="{Binding SendAccCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboBox}"/>
    </UniformGrid>
```

[RelayCommand and RelayCommand<T> classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68708995/how-to-create-and-use-async-command-abstract-class/68748914#68748914) used.